# How to save drawing on canvas as png file (linux)?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a painting application and I want to save my drawing on canvas widget as png file on my computer. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from functools import partial
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import filedialog,messagebox
from PIL import Image
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import pyautogui

class PaintingApp:
    x=y=None
    
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.window = window
        self.upper_frame = Frame(window)
        self.upper_frame.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10, pady=5,sticky="ew")
        self.lower_frame = Frame(window)
        self.lower_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=5,sticky="ew")
        self.canvas= Canvas(self.lower_frame,width=500,height=530,bg="white")
        self.canvas.grid()
        self.objects = [] #objects on canvas
        self.pen_size = 2
        self.pcolor = "black"
        self.pen = Button(self.upper_frame,text="Pen",command=partial(self.pen_draw,thickness=self.pen_size)) 
        self.pen.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=(10,160))
        self.bg = Button(self.upper_frame,text="Background",command= self.bgcolor) #change bg color
        self.bg.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=(100,10))
        
        self.upper_menu()
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.get_x_and_y)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event, b=self.pen_size: self.pen_draw(b,event))
        self.im = None
        
    def save_pic(self,event=None):
        file = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".png")
        x = self.canvas.winfo_rootx() + self.canvas.winfo_x()
        y = self.canvas.winfo_rooty() + self.canvas.winfo_y()
        x1 = x + self.canvas.winfo_width()
        y1 = y + self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x,y,x1,y1))
        self.im.save(file[19:])
        
    def pen_color(self,color):
        self.pcolor= color 
            
    def get_x_and_y(self,event):
        global x,y
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        
    def pen_draw(self,thickness,event=None):
        global x,y
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.get_x_and_y) # Bind to pen_draw function
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event, b=self.pen_size: self.pen_draw(b,event))        
        if event != None:
            self.objects.append(self.canvas.create_line((x, y, event.x, event.y), fill=self.pcolor,width=self.pen_size,capstyle=ROUND,smooth=True))
            x, y = event.x, event.y
    
    def upper_menu(self):
        self.menubar = Menu(window)
        self.menu1 = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.menu1.add_command(label="Save pic", command=self.save_pic)
        self.menu1.add_separator()
        self.menu1.add_command(label="Exit", command=window.destroy)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Settings", menu=self.menu1)
        self.menu2 = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.menu2.add_command(label="Open pic")
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Image", menu=self.menu2)
        self.window.config(menu=self.menubar)

    def bgcolor(self):
        chosen_color = askcolor(color=self.canvas["bg"])[1]
        self.canvas.configure(bg=chosen_color)
    
        
window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x450")
p = PaintingApp(window)

window.mainloop()
```

Now I have tried many many codes but it won't work. The code I provided above saves an all black picture which does not make any sense. I have tried using the module pyautogui as well but I still get the same result.

```
def save_pic(self,event=None):
        file = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".png")
        x = self.canvas.winfo_rootx() + self.canvas.winfo_x()
        y = self.canvas.winfo_rooty() + self.canvas.winfo_y()
        x1 = x + self.canvas.winfo_width()
        y1 = y + self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.im=pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x,y,x1,y1))
        self.im.save(file[19:])
```

Comment: Did you try to check whether `(x, y, x1, y1)` is the region you want?

Comment: @acw1668 I think it is the correct region. Either way the only thing I get is a black picture.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the black image issue. Actually using `.winfo_rootx()` and `.winfo_rooty()` are enough and don't need to add `.winfo_x()` and `.winfo_y()` (`.winfo_x()` and `.winfo_y()` returns 0 for your case).  You can test it by adding `padx=...` and `pady=...` in `self.canvas.grid(...)`, and you will get an image of incorrect region. And the window size is not large enough to show all the canvas, so region outside the window will be captured as well.   Also I don't understand why `file[19:]` is used instead of `file`.

Comment: @acw1668, FYI, it's reproducable if you test in Linux. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a screen shot library, you should wait until the backend UI framework(X11 in your case) finishes the drawing. Also you can use the `PIL.ImageGrab.grab()` in Pillow instead of pyscreenshot.

So do like this.(I fixed several errors in the original example, such as an incorrect path.)

```
...
from PIL import ImageGrab
...

class PaintingApp:
    ...
    def save_pic(self,event=None):
        file = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".png")
        def grab_and_save():
            x = self.canvas.winfo_rootx()
            y = self.canvas.winfo_rooty()
            x1 = x + self.canvas.winfo_width()
            y1 = y + self.canvas.winfo_height()
            self.im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x,y,x1,y1))
            self.im.save(file)
        self.window.update()
        self.window.after(1000, grab_and_save) # This waits 1000ms.
    ...
...
```

A better method will be to install Tkimg and export the bitmap on the canvas directly, but it will need some hard work. You can start with an unmaintained project, [python-tkimg](https://github.com/RedFantom/python-tkimg).

Comment: Note that OP has already used `Pillow.ImageGrab` module in the first code block.  Also when `save_pic()` is called, the drawing should be ready because the function is triggered by a menu action.

Comment: @acw1668, the OP used one in pyscreenshot, not one in Pillow. And you forgot to consider ```asksaveasfilename()``` which covers the canvas temporarily.

Comment: Please read OP first code block carefully, OP has used `ImageGrab` module there.  Also your solution may fix the overlapping of the file dialog, but not what OP said *"black image"*.

Comment: @acw1668, you missed the line ```import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab```. And is it matter the incorrect result to be a black image or not? Anyway let's wait the OP's response if you want to track down that black image case.

Comment: Sorry I did miss that line.

Comment: I tried this code and got the following error: "size, data = Image.core.grabscreen_x11(xdisplay)
OSError: X get_image failed: error 8 (73, 0, 1314)"

Comment: I strongly suspect Wayland. See [this issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6312). Let's blame GNOME for making Wayland as the default. Anyway if you have the ```gnome-screenshot```, upgrade ```Pillow``` and it will work even on Wayland.

Comment: Or you can install the ```gnome-screenshot``` package.